# Nested If Else Kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am writting Nested If else as follows:
What wrong with the code:

```
#if(item.ATTACHMENTS == 'Aftermarket'){#
                    #if(item.IS_ATT_AM_UPDATED == 'Y'){#
                        <img id="AftermarketBlueCircle" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/BlueCircle.png")" /> 
                    #}
                    else{#
                           <img id="AftermarketHalfCircle" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/HalfBlueCircle.jpg")" /> +
                    #}#
           else{#
                 #if(item.IS_ATT_TS_UPDATED == 'Y'){#
                        <img id="AftermarketBlueCircle" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/BlueCircle.png")" /> 
                    #}
                    else{#
                           <img id="AftermarketHalfCircle" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/HalfBlueCircle.jpg")" /> +
                    #}#    
                #}#
```

Please suggest

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: Ok, I can't help with lack of info, gl hf.

Answer (score 0):

```
#if(item.ATTACHMENTS == 'Aftermarket'){#
                    #if(item.IS_ATT_AM_UPDATED == 'Y'){#
                        <img id="AftermarketBlueCircle" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/BlueCircle.png")" /> 
                    #}
                    else{#
                        <img id="AftermarketHalfCircle" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/HalfBlueCircle.jpg")" /> 
                    #}#
           #}
            else{#
                    #if(item.IS_ATT_TS_UPDATED == 'Y'){#
                        <img id="AftermarketBlueCircle" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/BlueCircle.png")" /> 
                    #}
                    else{#
                        <img id="AftermarketHalfCircle" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/HalfBlueCircle.jpg")" /> 
                    #}#    
            #}#
```